# Cloud Invoice API

Tags: cloud-service, web-apis, invoicing

We are a software company, and we're looking for an api cloud base solution that would allow our hundreds of customers to create invoices. This product should have a tax approval from as much countries as possible.

What We mean by approval is that some countries tax authorities won't approve a business to charge for money, without testing its software, see how it produces invoices, and in some cases require adjustments and some api/electronic updated to the government (countries in Central and South America like Argentina for instance).

Answer (score 1):

You try [FreeAgent](https://www.freeagent.com/?referrer=45ds4ylh) where you can create users with certain permissions (e.g. creating invoices).

[image: FreeAgent accounting software, User Permissions, Invoices]

Comment: I need a product which has government approvals from as many countries as possible. Many customers around the world won't take a product without getting government approves on the process of invoices creation. That's the real problem.